# Doctrine Cache Symfony2 deleteByPrefix

Tags: php, caching, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to delete all my cache entries prefixed by a string, but my code returns :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache::deleteByPrefix()
```

and my code is

```
$deleted = $cachemanager->deleteByPrefix('catalog_');
```

like where I checked :  into the documentation of doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#deleting.

I need to clear the cache since controller, not from CLI...

Does someone as an alternative to this method 'deleteByPrefix()' ?

Comment: Your cache manager is actually a `FilesystemCache` object which has [no method](http://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.Common.Cache.Cache.html) `deleteByPrefix`. Make your `$cachemanager` an instance of an object which will *wrap* doctrine's cache and add your custom method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I come to use the Zend Framework cache bundle, who permit to delete by prefix...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the namespace. This will require reorganizing your caches. Or you can write your own implementation (extending Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache) which will implement deleteByPrefix(), but you'll use the ability to simply switch cache provider.

Comment: In using namespace, how can i do to delete all entries with specific namespace ? There's no 'deleteAll()' function...

Comment: Didn't you want to say: "you will ***lose*** the ability to switch cache provider"?