# How to delete Doctrine Cache with cache id prefix in symfony 2.5?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I am working on symfony 2.5 project with doctirne 2.4 as orm. I am using redis cache for caching query result.

I am able to delete individual query cache by query cache id in repository class with the help of following command:

```
$config = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
$queryCacheDriver = $config->getQueryCacheImpl();
$queryCacheDriver->delete(CACHE_PREFIX.$queryCacheId);
```

Now I want to delete group of query cache with some predined prefix. For example I want to delete all cached query related to some product with id xxx, so in this case cache prefix would be "product-xxx".

Is there any way to achive it?

Comment: I had to do the same thing, but the only way I found is Zend cache bundle : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpZendCacheBundle . older question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295738/doctrine-cache-symfony2-deletebyprefix

Comment: Ok thanks @Yenne Info. Let me know go though it and I will ask more help if needed.